# MVC3 Subdomain Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, subdomain

Hello I want to build a MVC3 app, which can handle simple and subdomain request.
The problem is with the **Routing** setup, and generation of correct **paths** inside
native mvc3 Html extensions ( *ActionLinks, Url.Content, Html.BeginForm, Ajax.BeginForm* )

So.. I have the following structure:

```
                   myDomain.com   // HomeController
                        |
Bar.myDomain.com <------|-------> Foo.myDomain.com
// BarController                  // FooController
```

The **HomeController**, is mapped to **myDomain.com** whose routes should look like:

```
myDomain.com                  // myDomain.com/{controller}/{action}  -- with defaults
myDomain.com/Home/Index       // myDomain.com/{controller}/{action}
myDomain.com/Home/Index/Id    // myDomain.com/{controller}/{action}/{id}
myDomain.com/en/Home/Index    // myDomain.com/{language}/{controller}/{action}
myDomain.com/en/Home/Index/Id // myDomain.com/{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

The **BarController**, is mapped to **Bar.myDomain.com** with routes:

```
Bar.myDomain.com               // {Controller}.myDomain.com/{action}  -- with defaults
Bar.myDomain.com/Index         // {Controller}.myDomain.com/{action}
Bar.myDomain.com/Index/Id      // {Controller}.myDomain.com/{action}/{id}
Bar.myDomain.com/en/Index      // {Controller}.myDomain.com/{language}/{action}
Bar.myDomain.com/en/Index/Id   // {Controller}.myDomain.com/{language}/{action}/{id}
```

**FooController** is the same as **BarController**

**THE PROBLEM:**

All the HtmlHelpers for the subdomain request's are generating path's like:

```
href="Bar.myDomain.com/en/Bar/Index"
href="Bar.myDomain.com/Bar/Index"
```

instead of:

```
href="Bar.myDomain.com/en/Index"
href="Bar.myDomain.com/Index"
```

Where and how to control the path, in accordance with it's route.

*Note 1.:* The URL in the AdressBar is generated OK. The problem is only with the path.

*Note 2.:* Please focus on IIS 7.0 integrated pipeline

*Note 3.:* My source of inspiration is from --->> [Here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx)

Thank you!