# How ActionLink, Html.BeginForm, Url.Content matches the right Route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

Could somebody explain to me please, wherefrom the ActionLink(and generally the Html helpers) is getting the right Route, and how it creates the right path. For example:

**For such a route**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

**The actionlink would look like:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyCoolLink","About","Home")
```

**The generated HTML would look like:**

```
<a href="/Home/About">About</a>
```

How to define a custom `href` path for the same route, lets say one that would look like this one:

```
  href="/About"
      or
  href="Home.myDomain.com/About"
```

Thank  you!

Comment: Here's a great basic explanation about mvc routing: [http://www.dotnetcurry.com/...](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814). And.. what exaclty are you trying to do with your routing?

Comment: Thank you for the link. The problem is much deeper, I described a part of it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943761/mvc3-subdomain-routing-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Url.Content`** :  Internally, **[`VirtualPathUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx)** is used when you use `Url.Content`.

And, `Html.ActionLink` ( as well as `Url.RouteUrl` ) , uses **[`RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getvirtualpath.aspx)** method. The `ActionLink` is actually specific to MVC(action and controller parameters ) and `Url.RouteUrl` is more of general purpose.

Microsoft has built the `ActionLink` methods as extension methods indeed. If these extension still do not serve your purpose, you are encouraged to write your own.

Download the source code from [**`here`**](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471) to see how Microsoft has implemented these extensions.

Also, Let's end up with a sample example on creating a custom `HtmlHelper` method.
Below namespaces/classes are good to read for when creating a custom `HtmlHelper` Methods.

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html Namespace
System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder Class
System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetaData Class
System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper Class
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate> Class
```

***The below example shows how to create/add custom `<span>` tags in `HTML.ActionLink`***

```
<a href="[action-link]"><span>[action-link text]</span></a>
```

To get this started, make a static class called `HtmlExtensions`.Lets create an extension method called `ActionLinkWithSpan` which will Extend the `HtmlHelper` Class.

```
namespace Tutorial.Examples
{
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkWithSpan(this HtmlHelper html,
string linkText,
string actionName,
string controllerName,
object htmlAttributes)
{
RouteValueDictionary attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
TagBuilder linkTag = new TagBuilder("a");
TagBuilder spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
spanTag.SetInnerText(linkText);

// Merge Attributes on the Tag you wish the htmlAttributes to be rendered on.
// e.g. linkTag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
spanTag.MergeAttributes(attributes);

UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
linkTag.Attributes.Add("href", url.Action(actionName, controllerName));
linkTag.InnerHtml = spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
return MvcHtmlString.Create(linkTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
}
}
```

***[This link](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/10/09/how-to-create-custom-mvc-extension-methods.aspx)*** is recommended to get more inside of creating custom MVC Methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you've pointed me to right sources. I'll dig more, and return with a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

ActionLink will generate a virtual path to the method using default or first matching route. So, you have the following options

1 Add entry to `RegisterRoutes` in `Global.asax` at higher priority (i.e. before other route definitions):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CustomRoute", // Route name
            "Something/{controller}/{action}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
    }
```

In this case `CustomRoute` will be applied to all matching routes, so this is quite global change.

2 Add `CustomRoute` with lower priority (i.e. after other routes) and target it in the view:

```
@Html.RouteLink("MyLink", "CustomRoute", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

3 Write your own extension method to HtmlHelper to provide functionality needed. Add a new file in your solution with the following code:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc {
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CustomActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, tring linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("<a href='http://myUrl.com/{0}/{1}'>{2}</a>", controllerName, actionName, linkText));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.CustomActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller")
```

4 Do not use ActionLink helper's method, just write your URL in the view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution is interesting, but actually i'd like to avoid re-engeneering all MVC3 Helpers. The problem it's not just with the ActionLinks, but with all Html Helpers. I suppose there must be a way to do it In a Custom Route Handler, or at higher level. But I don't understand where and how.. Thank you!

Comment: @Christian My understanding is that ActionLink will resolve your route using the first matching definition in routing table. You might try to re-order your route definitions to get required effect. You may also try using Html.RouteLink to target specific route definition.

Comment: And if I Map the routes inside Global.asax.cs with a custom Router class that inherits from Route. Could you please explain me where, and aprox. how should I implement the part which is responsible for matching the route with the path. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Christian I edited the answer to show how routes can be edited.